# Pyflakes "invalid syntax" and print function's variable in curly braces

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, python-3.6, sublime-text-plugin

I has Sublime Text 3 installed, SublimeLinter plugin and pyflakes linter.
In the pip pyflakes version is 1.6.0. OS win 7 x86.

```
my_name = 'Name'
print(f"My name is {my_name}.")
```

And here is the error:

```
SublimeLinter: pyflakes output:
ex3.py:9:30: invalid syntax
print(f"My name is {my_name}.")
                             ^
```

Also, with this construction i have no errors:

```
print("My name is {}.".format(my_name))
```

Code is runing just fine, but why pyflakes gives me this error then? Is it pyflakes issue or what?

Comment: Your pyflakes does not appear to be set to Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, see here:

https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/296

It seems to be fixed in current version...

Edit: Since you are on the latest version, maybe you are running into an issue of sublime-linter, like here:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublimelinter-pyflakes-not-matching-pyflakes-from-cli/31348/3

To test this, you could run the pyflakes command in the command line outside of sublime to see whether it works.

Edit2: As per the asker's comment, using `SublimeLinter-flake8` instead of `SublimeLinter-pyflakes` is compatible with f-strings from `python 3.6+`.

(Also, sorry for the double posted answer. And thanks for deleting one, @Andy. I don't know what happened there.)

Comment: Yea, from cmd pyflakes works fine, looks like it's linter's problem, so i'll try flake8 instead of pyflakes. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, the best way is to use **SublimeLinter-flake8** instead of *SublimeLinter-pyflakes* with **python 3.6+**, cause pyflakes linter is not compatable with 3.6 yet. Also flake8 do the same as pyflakes and much more.